# Celery using 'application/x-python-serialize' instead of `application/json`

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery

I'm using the `celery` module **v. 3.1.25** in Python 2.7 and Windows 10 to run a Celery worker. The results must be returned encoded in `json` and not `pickle`.

**Problem:** When the worker returns the result of a task, RabbitMQ management console shows the results to be `content_type:   application/x-python-serialize`. Why is it still `x-python-serialize` when we have set `task_serializer`, `result_serializer` and `accept_content` to `json`?

**proj/celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', 
    broker='amqp://test:test@192.168.1.26:5672//',    # running in Win10 VM
    backend='amqp://',
    task_serializer='json',
    result_serializer='json',
    accept_content=['application/json'],
    include=['proj.tasks'])
```

**proj/tasks.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app

@app.task
def myTask():
    ...
    return ...
```

Worker is started using

```
celery -A proj worker --loglevel=info
```

and gives a warning about the pickle serializer

```
Starting from version 3.2 Celery will refuse to accept pickle by default.

The pickle serializer is a security concern as it may give attackers
the ability to execute any command.  It's important to secure
your broker from unauthorized access when using pickle, so we think
that enabling pickle should require a deliberate action and not be
the default choice.

If you depend on pickle then you should set a setting to disable this
warning and to be sure that everything will continue working
when you upgrade to Celery 3.2::

    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle', 'json', 'msgpack', 'yaml']

You must only enable the serializers that you will actually use.


  warnings.warn(CDeprecationWarning(W_PICKLE_DEPRECATED))

 -------------- celery@Y-PC v3.1.25 (Cipater)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Windows-10-10.0.14393
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tasks:0x40ffeb8
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://test:**@192.168.1.26:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     amqp://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 12 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it help to change your Celery() config parameter to `accept_content=['json'],` instead of `application/json`?

Comment: Yes I tried `['json']` but the same warning appears and result is still encoded in `application/x-python-serialize`

Comment: Forgot to add that I'm using v3.1.25 of the `celery` python module.